# How to make Sublime Text 2 themes?

Tags: python, plugins, syntax, color-scheme, sublimetext

I've created a new syntax highlighting theme and am trying to make it available for as many editors as possible. My latest thing I'm tackling is a theme for Sublime Text 2. I have not too much knowledge of the theme sadly and need to make a quick theme for it ASAP. I've searched and google'd many times but still haven't found out how. Do you need to make a Python plugin, or something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sublime Text uses the same format for syntax coloring themes as TextMate (`.tmTheme` format).